# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor With No Initial Selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Can I populate DropDownListFor and NOT select any initial values without adding an empty value to the list? Basically, I need this field to be a required field, but I don't want to select anything initially, and I don't want to have an empty value because selecting an empty value wouldn't make sense since the field is required.

This is what I've tried so far. If I do the following, the first value gets selected:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModel,
someList.Select(p => new SelectListItem() {Text = p.name, Value = p.id})
```

If I add `optionLabel` parameter:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModel,
someList.Select(p => new SelectListItem() {Text = p.name, Value = p.id}),
string.Empty
```

it adds an empty value as the first item, which is not what I want...

I also tried explicitly deselecting all items:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModel,
someList.Select(p => new SelectListItem() {Text = p.name, Value = p.id, Selected = false})
```

This still selects the first item.

Is there a way around this? I can clear the value with jQuery like this:

```
$('#myDropdown').val('');
```

But I wanted to see if there's a way to do this natively with Razor.

Comment: The point of adding the label option is so that if a user does not select a value, the `ModelState` is invalid. Why don't you want to do this?

Comment: And if you want to preselect an item, then set the value of property `MyModel` to a value that matches one of your options.

Comment: Because allowing user to re-select an empty option, or something labeled "Please select something" just doesn't make sense - it's a required value, so why even have those options. And also, if I can clear the dropdown with js or jQuery, why shouldn't I be able to do the same with Razor?

Comment: But clearing the value using javascript is exactly the same as generating a blank option. I think you might be alone in thinking that it _just doesn't make sense_ (and no, you cannot do it with razor code)

Comment: Sorry, but clearing with js is NOT the same thing. If I use `optionLabel`, dropdown has `optionLabel`, `item1`, `item2`, etc. Without `optionLabel` dropdown has `item1`, `item2`, etc. and clearing it with js simply clears the dropdown, without adding an extra (and unnecessary) option to the list.

Comment: _Can I populate DropDownListFor and NOT select any initial values without adding an empty value to the list_ **NO**

Comment: OK, thanks for the replies.